# How to avoid dependency injection in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-import

I'm trying to figure out how to avoid dependency injection in my project. There is a file `notifications.py` in app directory.

File `notifications.py` contains methods for sending emails to admin and users. To get admins email, I need to check object of `SystemData` model. But in models, I use notifications.

**models**

```
class SystemData(models.Model):
    admin_alerts_email = models.EmailField(verbose_name=u'Emailová adresa admina')
    contact_us_email = models.EmailField(verbose_name=u'Adresa kontaktujte nás')
    waiting_threshold = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name=u'Maximálny počet minút čakania')

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ....
    def save(...):
        notifications.send_message_to_admin('message')
```

**notifications.py**

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from models import SystemData

def send_message_to_admin(message):
    mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=[SystemData.objects.all().first().admin_email])
    mail.send()
```

Django returns that it can't import `SystemData`.

Do you know what to do?

**EDIT:**

```
stacktrace
```

[image: stacktrace]

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace? It may be as simple as replacing models with .models at the import line

Comment: I've added the stacktrace at the bottom of the question

Comment: I tried to replace from models import SystemData to from .models import SystemData and it did not help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve circular dependencies in functions by using inline imports:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ....
    def save(...):
        from .notifications import send_message_to_admin
        send_message_to_admin('message')
```

This will delay the import statement until the function is actually executed, so the `models` module has already been loaded. The `notifications` module can then safely import the `models` module.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using circular imports you can either do it like that:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import SystemData, SomeModel


@receiver(post_save, sender=SomeModel)
def send_message_to_admin(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    message = 'message'
    mail = EmailMessage(
        subject, 
        message, 
        to=[SystemData.objects.all().first().admin_email]
    )
    mail.send()
```

and at the end of models.py put

`from .notifications import *`

or use newest approach with AppConfig to register signals (that's what your notifications actually do)

see: https://chriskief.com/2014/02/28/django-1-7-signals-appconfig/

that way it will load when app registry is ready and you'll avoid circular imports, so that line:

`from .notifications import *`

can be dropped from models.py

AppConfig can be used in a more generic way as well allowing you to import models like that:

```
from django.apps import apps
Model = apps.get_model('app_name', 'Model')
```